# Federated Identity: how to I inject the httpContext for testing purposes?

Tags: unit-testing, wif

I am unit testing asp.net mvc code by creating an object that inherits HttpContextBase and is injected into my controllers.

```cs
myfooController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new FakeHttpContext();
```

By doing this, I can mock a wide variety of asp.net properies: url, referrer, user agent, cookies, etc.  It works great.

I'm writing unit tests to cover our FederatedIdentity controller that decodes RelyingPArty signing requests and handles them appropriately.  My FakeHttpContext lets me test a wide variety of scenarios: null signIn requests, bad shared secrets, etc.

On our current WIF project, we need to make a call to the static class  FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler to do some cookie stuff.

When I do this from my unit test, it blows up because the HttpContext.Current is null. The SessionAuthenticationModule appears to use HttpContext.Current, which cannot be set to my fake context.  Since HttpContext.Current does not inherit from HttpContextBase, I cannot set any relevant properties to do useful testing things.

Am I right in my conclusion that in 2011, someone at Microsoft created enormously important authentication code that is completely and utterly not unit-testable?  Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you handling the actual authentication?

Do you have valid session and claims authentication objects?

[SelfSTS](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SelfSTS/) is very useful for unit test scenarios like you describe.

Comment: Marked as answer not because it fixes the core problem, but because SelfSTS helps testing a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) by Scott Hanselman. He shows the mocking of HttpContext and other ASP.NET artifacts for another purpose (e.g. FileUploads), but I use the same techniques:

Essentially:

```cs
var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
user.Setup(p => p.Identity.IsAuthenticated ).Returns(true);

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.Setup( ctx => ctx.User)
       .Returns(user.Object);

var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(con => con.HttpContext)
                 .Returns(context.Object);

var c = new YourController();
c.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object; 

....
```

I would probably not unit test against WIF though.

Comment: Yeah, that's where the inspiration for fake contexts came from.  Trouble is, setting the controller context is great, but the SessionAuthenticationModule appears to use HttpContext.Current, which cannot be set to my fake context.  grrr!